# uuid key in prop appears as an object? REACTjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, uuid

Hello peepz of the web,

I've ran into mysterious corridor, which's too dark for me to see what the hell I'm going.. would love someone's flashlight to shine the way.

I have created a simple, poor to do list program.

It's combined from **Task.js**, **TaskList.js** and **NewTaskForm.js**.

From the **NewTaskForm.js** I'm retrieving input, passing it to the parent, **TaskList.js**.

On **TaskList.js** I'm adding a key to the task object:

```
handleSubmit(task2add){
    let keyid = v4();
    console.log(keyid);
    let task2addWithID = { ...task2add, id: {keyid}, key: {keyid}};
    this.setState(st => ({
        todoArr: [...st.todoArr, task2addWithID],
    }));
}
```

Now, in **TaskList.js**, in my **render function**, I'm creating Tasks:

```
    render() {
        let tasklist = this.state.todoArr.map(task => (
            <div>
                <Task 
                    taskTitle={task.title} 
                    taskText={task.text} 
                    key={task.key}
                    id={task.id}
                    handleRemove={this.handleRemove}
                    handleEdit={this.handleEdit}
                />
            </div>
        ));

    return (
      <div>
        
        <h1>TaskList</h1>
        <div className='TaskList'>
            <div className='TaskList-title'>
            {tasklist}
            </div>
            <NewTaskForm key={1} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
        </div>

      </div>
    )
  }
```

now, what is so confusing for me is why when I'm doing in my **Tasks.js** class:

```
console.log(this.props.id);
```

it prints me an object?
[image]

I would expect it to.. print me a value? where along the way did it wrap it with an object?

Full (shitty) code below.

Plus #1, if anyone knows to tell me why still I get the warning the key, even though, at least for my poor experience, I have given it a key?

Plus #2, why even when I send the handleRemove function in **TaskList.js** the proper id, it doesn't erase the bloody task? :-(

Regards!

**Task.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './Task.css';

export default class Task extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
    }

    handleRemove(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        console.log("MY ID MANNN");
        console.log(this.props.id);
        this.props.handleRemove(this.props.id.keyid);
        console.log("CALLED");
    }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className='Task'>
        <div className='Task-title'>
        {this.props.taskTitle}
        </div>
        <div className='Task-text'>
            {this.props.taskText}
        </div>
        <div>
            <button className='Task-buttons'>Edit</button>
            <button className='Task-buttons' onClick={this.handleRemove}>Delete</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**NewTaskForm.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {v4} from 'uuid';


export default class NewTaskForm extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title: "", text: "", editing: false
        }
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        // this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        
        // let stateWithID = { ...this.state, id: useId()};

        this.props.handleSubmit(this.state);


        this.setState({
            title: "",
            text: ""
        })
    }

    handleChange(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value
        });
    }


    render() {

       

    return (
      <div>
        
        <h2>Insert new Task:</h2>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
            <input  
                name='title'
                id='title'
                type='text'
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                value={this.state.title}
                 />
        <div>
        <label htmlFor="text">text</label>
            <input  
                name='text'
                id='text'
                type='text'
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                value={this.state.text}
            />

        </div>
        <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**TaskList.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import NewTaskForm from './NewTaskForm';
import Task from './Task';
import './TaskList.css';
import {v4} from 'uuid';

export default class TaskList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            todoArr: [ 
                // {title: "test", text: "this shit", key: "", id: ""},
                // {title: "test2", text: "this shi2", key: "", id: ""},
                // {title: "test3", text: "this shi3", key: "", id: ""}
        
        ],
            isEditing: false,
        }
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
        this.handleEdit = this.handleEdit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(task2add){
        let keyid = v4();
        console.log(keyid);
        let task2addWithID = { ...task2add, id: {keyid}, key: {keyid}};
        this.setState(st => ({
            todoArr: [...st.todoArr, task2addWithID],
        }));
    }

    handleRemove(keyid){
        console.log("IN HANDLE REMOVE");
        console.log(keyid);
        this.setState(st => ({
            todoArr: st.todoArr.filter(n => n.keyid !== keyid )
        }));
    }

    handleEdit(id){

    }
  
    render() {
        let tasklist = this.state.todoArr.map(task => (
            <div>
                <Task 
                    taskTitle={task.title} 
                    taskText={task.text} 
                    key={task.key}
                    id={task.id}
                    handleRemove={this.handleRemove}
                    handleEdit={this.handleEdit}
                />
            </div>
        ));

    return (
      <div>
        
        <h1>TaskList</h1>
        <div className='TaskList'>
            <div className='TaskList-title'>
            {tasklist}
            </div>
            <NewTaskForm key={1} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
        </div>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have created an object here:

```
{ ...task2add, id: {keyid}, key: {keyid}};
```

```
{keyid}
```

is the same as

```
{keyid: keyid}
```

You wanted to do this:

```
{ ...task2add, id: keyid, key: keyid};
```

Comment: So silly of me, and yet, I was stuck over this for so long.. bless you, sir!

Comment: cheers. yet, for some reason, I still cannot erase the tasks.. any ideas?

Comment: You didn't show us how `handleRemove` looks like

Comment: It's in the bottom of the question (Y) I've added the 'full' code ;p

Comment: `this.props.handleRemove(this.props.id.keyid)` - this doesn't make any sense now. You wanted to use `this.props.id` probably

Comment: Yeah, that's the only thing I have changed in addition to your insight regarding the 'object issue', still, the task is not being removed ;[

Comment: nvm, I have found my problem. I was within TaskList.js, in handleRemove function, using filter function wrongly, forgetting that n is an object within todoArr, and no the id itself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming its because you're setting the state like this:

```
  let task2addWithID = { ...task2add, id: {keyid}, key: {keyid}};
```

The id attribute is assigned an object. If you did:

```
  let task2addWithID = { ...task2add, id: keyid, key: {keyid}};
```

console logging id should print out a string